# How do I run Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0.1?

Tags: installation, cisco

I have a problem running Packet tracer 6.0.1 on Ubuntu 13.04.

I have a downloaded file from Cisco Netspace - this file had not extension. I added the extension `tar.gz` to this file and I could unpack it to a location with other folders and files, there was a file `install` too.

This was a `.bin` file and I used `sudo chmod +x` on this file and I used `./filename` and installation has been launched I had to accept licence and so on.

After successfully installation I tried to launch Packet Tracer and nothing happened. Please help me, how can I correctly install and run Packet Tracer.

Note that I'm new in using Linux.

Comment: Did any of the answers helped you?  If so, please mark that as an answer.

Comment: It's possible you haven't enabled 32 bit architecture support.  Do `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Answer (score 6):

You probably did not follow the correct procedure. For one: nowhere does it state you need to rename the file to an extension that claims it is a compressed archive. This is one method that works:

1. Re-download Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0 for Ubuntu.
2. Open up Downloads folder, rename to `CiscoPacketTracer6.0`.
3. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).
4. Type in:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```

   And type in your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Then type:

   ```
   cd Downloads
   ls
   chmod +x CiscoPacketTracer6.0
   ./CiscoPacketTracer6.0
   ```
6. Next, click the <kbd>space</kbd> bar to go to the bottom (You'll see a % at the bottom left of terminal) of the EULA and press the <kbd>y</kbd> button to accept the terms and conditions. 
   After that, sit back and wait until it's done.
7. Next, click on Ubuntu symbol and search "Packet" on your computer. You should see the Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0 icon. Right mouse click on that and packet tracer should open.

If this does not work please edit your answer and PM me.

The installer puts its files into:

```
/usr/local/PacketTracer6/
```

The executable is:

```
/usr/local/PacketTracer6/bin/PacketTracer6
```

So you can also create a link in `/usr/local/bin` to be able to run from the command-line:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/PacketTracer6/bin/PacketTracer6 /usr/local/bin/
```

Finally, for reference, to find the path and arguments used when a program was run from the gui, you can use: `ps auxfwww | less`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Tod! It's great that you have typed all the steps, however, I think the person that asked the question has already gone through all of this. His problem is that when he clicks on the "Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0 icon", it doesn't open up.

Comment: @Alaa OP said change the extension to `tar.gz` and nowhere in the documentation it says so. Also, he said that he don't know how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I installed Packet Tracer 6.0.1 on Ubuntu 13.10:

Downloaded "**Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0.1 for Linux - Ubuntu installation (no tutorials)**" from the cisco's www.netacad.com website.

Yes, it doesn't have an extension.

I made a copy of it and renamed **PT601.tar.gz**

I chose a short name just for ease of use and the extension should be `.tar.gz`.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

```
cd "location of the PT601.tar.gz"
```

For example:

```
cd /home/Downloads
sudo chmod a+x PT601.tar.gz
bash ./PT601.tar.gz
```

It took me a few days being beginner on Linux, and Cisco didn't give any instructions.

Hopefully this will help a few people getting by with Packet Tracer 6.0.1 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

As you have downloaded `Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0.1` for Linux, don't change its extension but change its name to use commands easily, let's say you have changed it's name to xxx.bin and its under home directory-

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a terminal and then change the permission for that file by using the following command:

```
chmod +x xxx.bin
```

and run

```
./xxx.bin
```

and after that press <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, and then <kbd>y</kbd> for `yes` and provide your password.

If you are using 64 bit System Architecture, you have to install `ia32-libs` by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
```

If you are not sure about the Architecture use:

```
arch
```

or

```
uname -m
```

The downloaded file would be of approximately 77Mbs. Check it's correct size before initiating the procedure.