# Packet Tracer 6.0.1 - problem with running (error while loading shared libraries: libQtScriptTools.so.4: ...)

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, shared-library

I have installed smoothly PTR 6.0.1 according to this site ([How do I run Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335785/how-do-i-run-cisco-packet-tracer-6-0-1)), but when I want to run it this error appears:

```
PacketTracer6: error while loading shared libraries: libQtScriptTools.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have Ubuntu version 13.10. 
Can somebody help me with this? Thanx.

**EDIT**:
Hello, so I have installed this libqt4-scriptools:i386 library and now this error appears:

```
PacketTracer6: error while loading shared libraries: libQt3Support.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

I find this library here:/usr/local/PacketTracer6/lib/libQt3Support.so.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PacketTracer6 tries to load a library called `libQtScriptTools.so.4`, but cannot find it. This usually is caused by one of two things.

---

**Library missing**

The first, more likely cause: The library is not installed. Luckily, the fix is easy.

Run

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-scripttools:i386
```

That will install the 32-bit-version of the library, which is necessary because Cisco ships a 32-bit version of PacketTracer6 only.

---

**Problems with the library path**

The second cause: The library is installed, but PacketTracer cannot find it. In order to work around that, you could run

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libQtScriptTools.so.4 /path/to/packettracer
```

after replacing the paths with the real ones from your system.

---

**Update**: Since PacketTracer also seems to need `libQt3Support.so.4`, but doesn't use the version it ships with, you will have to install `libqt4-qt3support:i386` as well.

Comment: Please add any additional information about the problem to your post using the [edit function](http://askubuntu.com/posts/389118/edit). Error messages in comments are very hard to decipher.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines of code can be found in the inside the "install" file.

```
sudo apt-get -y install lib32z1
sudo apt-get -y install lib32ncurses5
sudo apt-get -y install lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get -y install libgcc1:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libstdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libqtwebkit4:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libqt4-scripttools:i386
```

Once the above packages are installed you should be able to run the application.

**Note**:
`lib32bz2-1.0` failed to install on Ubuntu 15.04 and the application still seams to run just fine.