# PacketTracer 7 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cisco

I am trying to install Cisco's Packet Tracer to do some training on Ubuntu 16.04, I got through the install process but when I run it I get:

```
$ ./PacketTracer7 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now I usually try to google as much as I can before asking but there isn't much on the topic and this error doesn't really give very much information as to what went wrong.

I decided to check out the required packages, and it looks like everything checks out so far:

```
$ ldd PacketTracer7 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffebf7fa000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f7179b88000)
    libQtWebKit.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4 (0x00007f7177690000)
    libQtScriptTools.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScriptTools.so.4 (0x00007f71773c8000)
    libQtScript.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4 (0x00007f7176f00000)
    libQtSvg.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4 (0x00007f7176ca0000)
    libQtXml.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtXml.so.4 (0x00007f7176a58000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f7175d60000)
    libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00007f7175a08000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f7175510000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f71752f0000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7174f68000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7174c58000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7174a40000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7174670000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7174468000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7174248000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f7174038000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f7173dd8000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f7173bb0000)
    libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007f7173970000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f71735b0000)
    libgstapp-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f71733a0000)
    libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f7173168000)
    libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f7172ee0000)
    libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f7172c80000)
    libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f7172a18000)
    libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f71726e8000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7172490000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7172178000)                                        
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f7171ea0000)                                      
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f7171c58000)                                
    libQtOpenGL.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4 (0x00007f7171950000)                                    
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f71716c0000)                                                      
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f7171380000)                                              
    libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0x00007f7171160000)                                          
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f7170eb0000)                                    
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f7170ca8000)                                                
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f7170a88000)                                              
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f7170878000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f7170660000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7170458000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055dad4c96000)
    libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f71700c0000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f716fe98000)
    libgsttag-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f716fc58000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f716f9d8000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f716f7d0000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f716f5c8000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f716f358000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f716f128000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f716eef0000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f716ec08000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f716e9e0000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f716e770000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f716e568000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f716e360000)
    libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f716c8a8000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f716c6a0000)
```

I'm not sure where to go to further troubleshoot this problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Probably due to incompatibility between system Qt and the Qt that Packet Tracer is built against. See http://pyther.net/2010/01/packettracer-5-2-1-linux/ for some related help and see if it works.

Comment: check this installation guide http://askubuntu.com/questions/335785/how-do-i-run-cisco-packet-tracer-6-0-1

Comment: Hi, this is a newer version with quite different requirements than the ones in the links you provided. Thanks for looking though!

Comment: I specifically installed Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox guests because that is the claimed PacketTracer x86_64 compatible distribution. Segfault!... OK, so really, what does PacketTracer need to run?

Answer (score 2):

Found a [solution here](http://www.atechnote.com/2016/09/how-to-run-packettracer-on-ubuntu-1604.html):

There is a problem due to the mixture of QT versions on app folder and the system, so this method makes the packettracer to use the system libraries mostly.

assuming default install dir /opt/pt

1- create a directory call libwebkit and copy all the libqtwebkit of packettracer to the directory or

```
$ sudo mkdir /opt/pt/libwebkit
$ sudo cp /opt/pt/lib/libQtWebKit.so* /opt/pt/libwebkit/
```

2- then to run packettracer using the following command

```
$  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pt/libwebkit/ /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7
```

Thanks to [Dara Theam](https://plus.google.com/110541335311005881604)

3- So you have to edit init script **/opt/pt/packettracer** to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Starting Packet Tracer 7.0 
PTDIR=/opt/pt
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PTDIR/libwebkit/
pushd $PTDIR/bin > /dev/null
./PacketTracer7 "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
popd > /dev/null
```

Comment: This solved it for me on Ubuntu 16.10, thank you so much!

Comment: When I run the command in *step 2*, I get: `/opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libQtScriptTools.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Is there any way I can fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it the startup script "packettracer" so the packaged libraries get used.

Comment: I still get the "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error when using that command.

Comment: I do run the startup script... And then watch the Segfault.