# Installing Cisco Packet Tracer 7 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, software-installation, 16.10, cisco

I am new to Linux. Trying to install Packet Tracer 7 on Ubuntu 16.10 with no success. Basically tried two different methods from Ubuntu previous answers namely:
Method one:
[How do I run Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335785/how-do-i-run-cisco-packet-tracer-6-0-1)

1. Re-download Cisco Packet Tracer 6.0 for Ubuntu.
2. Open up Downloads folder, rename to CiscoPacketTracer6.0.
3. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).
4. Type in:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```

And type in your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

5. Then type:

   - `cd Downloads`
   - `ls`
   - `chmod +x CiscoPacketTracer6.0`
   - `./CiscoPacketTracer6.0`

I got stuck here getting the error: `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.

Method two:

From the same link above second answer:basically the same method, the difference is:

- `sudo chmod a+x PT601.tar.gz`
- `bash ./PT601.tar.gz`

Got stuck again with the error: `cannot execute binary file`

Then searched again and found that it might be a 64/32 bit error so I downloaded the 32bit version from netacad and tried the first method again and got the same error: `cannot execute binary file`.
Then I tried the second method and got: `cannot execute binary file:  Exec format error`. 
The netacad provides the following two versions:

Linux Desktop Version 7.0 English

1. Ubuntu 14.04 supported for 64 bit;
2. Ubuntu 12.04 supported for 32 bit

I have tried both with no success. I couldn't find any kind of help on netacad site on how to install those two files.
As I am totally new to Linux, I would appreciate it if the (possible) answer is detailed. I am not familiar with terms and methods yet.

Comment: there seem to be unstated dependencies for CPT.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I installed Packet Tracer.  After downloading the file, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal in the same folder the trace file was downloaded.  When it opens, I ran the command below, and that started the installation process:

```
sudo ./install
```

Once the installation was done, I ran

```
packettracer
```

And that started the app.

[image]

You also can create a [desktop shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop) for the application

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to install, create a desktop launcher and associate files for Packet Tracer 7.

**Install**

Download Packet Tracer 7 to your Downloads directory from NetAcad

Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) and extract the tar file :

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ tar xzvf PacketTracer70_64bit_linux.tar.gz
```

Start the installation :

```
$ sudo ~/Downloads/PacketTracer70/./install
```

You will be ask to accept the terms and select a location to install (press ‘Enter’ to select the default location /opt/pt )

You can now launch PT7 by typing ‘packettracer’ in a terminal

Delete the installation files :

```
$ sudo rm -rf ~/Downloads/{PacketTracer70,PacketTracer70_64bit_linux.tar.gz}
```

**Create a Desktop launcher**

Copy the .desktop file to your home directory with this command (edit this command if you installed PT7 in another directory) :

```
$ cp /opt/pt/bin/Cisco-PacketTracer.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/Cisco-PacketTracer.desktop
```

Open and edit the new .desktop file (you can use gedit or nano if you’re not comfortable with vim) :

```
$ vim ~/.local/share/applications/Cisco-PacketTracer.desktop
```

Replace the path for both the *Exec* and *Icon* lines (edit the path if you installed PT7 in a different directory) :

```
Exec=/opt/pt/packettracer
Icon=/opt/pt/art/app.png
```

Make the file executable :

```
$ chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/Cisco-PacketTracer.desktop
```

You can now launch PT7 from the dash and lock it on the launcher if you want.

**Associate Packet Tracer files**

In order to launch PT7 from your .pk* files

Create the following directories :

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.local/share/mime/packages ~/.local/share/icons
```

Copy the .xml files to packages directory :

```
$ cp /opt/pt/bin/{Cisco-pka.xml,Cisco-pkt.xml,Cisco-pkz.xml} ~/.local/share/mime/packages/.
```

Copy and rename the .png files to icons directory :

```
$ cp /opt/pt/art/{pka.png,pkt.png,pkz.png} ~/.local/icons/{application-x-pka.png,application-x-pkt.png,application-x-pkz.png}
```

Update the mime and desktop databases :

```
$ sudo update-mime-database $HOME/.local/share/mime
$ sudo update-desktop-database $HOME/.local/share/applications
```

Reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on youtube and it worked for me.
The video was "Install Packet Tracer 7 on Ubuntu" by Christian Augusto Romero Goyzueta.

Open terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>). Then use the following commands:

```
ls Downloads
```

You will see the files listed which are in the `Downloads` folder.
In my computer the file name is `PacketTracer7.tar.gz`

```
tar -zxvf Downloads/PacketTracer7.tar.gz
```

Now some output will appear, then change file directory (cd) as follows:

```
cd PacketTracer70/
```

Now list directory:

```
$ ls
art          eula.txt    install    saves         templates
backgrounds  extensions  languages  set_ptenv.sh  tpl.linguist
bin          help        lib        Sounds        tpl.packettracer
```

The needed file is `install`. So now type the command:

```
sudo bash install
```

Then type the password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Cisco license agreement will display; keep pressing on the space bar until you go through all the terms, where after user will be prompt by:

```
Do you accept the terms of the EULA? (Y)es/(N)o
```

type `y` or `yes` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Another prompt again:

```
Enter location to install Cisco Packet Tracer or press enter for default [/opt/pt]:
```

just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the default location will be used.
Again another prompt will appear:

```
Should we create a symbolic link "packettracer" in 
/usr/local/bin for easy Cisco Packet Tracer startup? [Yn]
```

just press `y`. Then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now use the list directory command again:

```
$ ls
art          eula.txt    install    saves         templates
backgrounds  extensions  languages  set_ptenv.sh  tpl.linguist
bin          help        lib        Sounds        tpl.packettracer`
```

The needed file is `set_ptenv.sh`. So the following command should be used now:

```
sudo bash set_ptenv.sh
packettracer
```

Cisco Packet Tracer will open and Cisco username and password will be requested.

Comment: `sudo bash set_ptenv.sh` is the needed file for?