# How do I install "Cisco Packet Tracer" on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, cisco

I have made an effort of installing "Cisco Packet Tracer" on 18.04lts without success kindly can anybody help ?

Comment: what have you tried? what went wrong? you need to be more specific for us to help. did you follow directions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/864226/installing-cisco-packet-tracer-7-on-ubuntu-16-10